# Scrollbar on top of listbox issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to attach a scrollbar element to the side of the listbox element.

When I try to put scrollbar to the side of the listbox, the scrollbar jumps to top of the listbox. I tried to grid it and pack it. None of them seems to work.

It looks like this:

[image: Window My app and scrollbar on top of listbox]

The code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title('My app')
        super().__init__(root)
        self.grid()
        self.createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):
        self.listbox = Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.listbox)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ma = MyApp(Tk())
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that I was trying to accomplish can't be done in Tkinter. I tried to use Wx module and it works great.